# Xcode 7 Vertical Scroll View Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, size-classes

I'm having trouble creating a vertical only scrollview in Xcode 7.3. I've followed a couple of tutorials on SO and other places but for some reason it seems that my topmost view's width extends past the screen or is shifted to the left. The scroll view is restricted to vertical scrolling only, which is my intent but the content appears partially off the screen.

I try to horizontally center buttons and pin to the top and bottom of the content view. On the simulator they appear half off the screen to the left but they appear fine in the storyboard with no constraint issues. I even preview the view 3.5, 4, and 4.7 inch screens in the assistant editor and it looks as I expect it. But when I run it on the simulator it's messed up. Also the background of the Content View is supposed to be white (for testing purposes) but it's showing the gray color of the top-most view.

This is what I do along with pictures of my constraints

1. Add Scroll View and pin to the super views top, bottom, left, right (0,0,0,0)
2. Add Content View and pin to Scroll View top, bottom, left, right (0,0,0,0) and also add a constant height of 1000.
3. I ctrl+drag from Content View to View (parent of Scroll View) and set equal width constraint.
4. Place 2 buttons inside Content View pin 1 to the top and the other to the bottom. Both are horizontally centered as well.

This is what it looks like on the simulator.

[Simulator-Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZfrG.png)

And this is what I its supposed to look like on the iPhone screens.

[Storyboard-Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsYeB.png)

Comment: Which view is not setting properly scrollview or content view

Comment: I think it's the content view. It's set up to be equal widths as the screen view but it doesn't appear to be at run time.

Comment: Give it horizontal centre constraint and than check

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq that did it. Thanks a lot! I think you added the answer as a comment. If you add it as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Answer added kindly accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it horizontal centre constraint and than check

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set all constrain correctly . But still check this once again.

Step 1 :- Remove tick Adjust scrollview insets

[image]

Step 2 :- As you said Give Leading , Trialing , Top , Bottom = 0 .

[image]

Step 3 :- same as step , set Leading , Trialing , Top , Bottom = 0 from           superview

[image]

Warning :- You need to check both the constrain inspector because sometimes it takes Leading space from -20.

Step 4 :- Set constrain to 1 st button  Top , Leading , Trialing

[image]

Step 5 :- Set Leading , Trialing , Vertical space to button 1 and Bottom (bottom from UIView)

If you give vertical spacing to button1 and give bottom to view then you dont need to set contentsize or else , it will scroll Automatically.

[image]

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that your answer helped me remove the extra padding on top from the navigation bar. Ultimately, I had to add a horizontal constraint on the content view.

Comment: I think if you give centre horizontal cinstrain then , then your view can not be scroll.so , you need to modify constant for that. So set centre horizontaly is nit proper way according to me.